# How can I make Java works in browser on Ubuntu (64bit) in 2017?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, java, browser, plugins

I need to run some old browser-based java applications. But when today I open my Firefox and try to open this app, I found that Java plugin not works. I searched Internet and find that new Firefox not longer supports Java plugin (Chrome and other browsers too). So how can I make this in-browser java application run?
I use Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

Comment: Some browser-based Java applications may be possible to launch using `appletviewer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

| Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit |

- First, I have updated Java to have the latest version.

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
  ```
- Then I download and unpack archive with 64-bit ESR Firefox (older version - v.45) from [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/)
- Then I close my 'standard' previously installed Firefox and run 'firefox' file from the extracted folder of the version 45 archive.

And after that I open my site and successfully run Java application from it.

Comment: Did work in Ubuntu 17.04. But downloaded firefox from this ftp: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.9.0esr/ and disabled automatic updates in firefox option's advanced section